# Is $\mathbb R^J$ normal in the box topology when $J$ is uncountable?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, box-topology

Question:

> Is $\mathbb R^J$ normal in the box topology when $J$ is uncountable?

I know $\mathbb R^J$ is not normal in the product topology, see ["Proof" that $\mathbb{R}^J$ is not normal when $J$ is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65407/proof-that-mathbbrj-is-not-normal-when-j-is-uncountable) ;

I also know $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ is normal in the box topology assuming the continuum hypothesis, see [Is it still an open problem whether $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ is normal in the box topology?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314887/is-it-still-an-open-problem-whether-mathbbr-omega-is-normal-in-the-box-top).

That's the motivation for this problem. Unfortunately, the above two theorems don't imply anything about the normality of $\mathbb R^J$. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Box topology" ? It's not a standard naming...

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe box product sounds better?

Comment: A closed subspace of a normal space is normal. $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^k$ if $k$ is uncountable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet So you are suggesting this problem is likely to be open, right?

Comment: If the countable product isn't normal (which is open) then so would the higher powers be.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What about assuming the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: If we assume CH we know nothing more about the uncountable case.

Answer (score 4):

It is known that the space $\square (\omega +1)^{\omega_1}$ is not normal. This is an amazing result of B. Lawrence, 1996: Failure of normality in the box product of uncountably many real lines.